# Хранить перевод в файле или БД?

Tags: php, mysql

Планирую хранить переводы элементов интерфейса в зависимости от пола посетителя *(м/ж)*, количества сущностей *(лет/года)* и от того, кто просматривает - владелец или гость *(мне/ему)*. Получается довольно много записей на каждый элемент.

Где лучше это хранить, с точки зрения производительности: в файлах или в БД?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения производительности, лучше всего хранить перевод в памяти. Проще всего для этой цели воспользоваться библиотекой [gettext](http://php.net/gettext).

Answer (score 1):

В БД, однозначно! Это, во-первых куда удобнее( структурированный доступ ) и во-вторых, это быстрее, чем работа с файлами. Конструкция `fopen() -> fwrite()/fread() -> fclose()` (классическая) жадно кушает ресурсы.

Answer (score 0):

Наверное я не совсем понял суть вопроса, но походу речь идет почти о том же, что и Интернационализация. То я бы посоветовал посмотреть, как реализовано это во фрэймворке YII: [Интернационализация](http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.i18n)